# Ruby on Rails in OS X Snow Leopard - what versions do I have installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sqlite, installation

I've been trying to get Ruby on Rails working on my Snow Leopard 64-bit MacBook Pro. I followed the instructions in Agile Web Development with Rails and everything *seemed* to install fine (and allows me to create a demo site), but I got an error to do with `sqlite3` when trying to start the web server on my simple demo site (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027363/sqlite3-error-after-rails-3-beta-4-install) for details of the error I get). I *suspect* at some point I've managed to install the wrong version or achitecture of a package (I'm using MacPorts) which is causing the problems.

**Note:** I'm not re-asking that previous question, what I want to know is **Is there a way I can determine *exactly* which versions of each ruby package I have installed, and for what architecture they were built?**

I've (foolishly) lost track of the `sudo port install` lines I've typed so I'm not sure what's currently on my system to try to diagnose how to fix it.

I'd like a list of something like:

```
Ruby v.1.9.2 - 64bit
Rails v 2.1 - 32bit
... etc.
```

Alternatively can I do something (short of reinstalling OS X and XCode) to remove all traces of Ruby from my system and start again?

---

If you have advice on how to fix the `sqlite3` error I'm getting, please answer on the question linked to above, not here.

Comment: `gem list` will list the gems you have installed (with versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo port list installed`  will show you what ports you have installed

I would look at installing RVM (http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)   as well (as it allows you to keep all the rubies separate). and makes it easy to totally remove a ruby and all its gems/etc..

Did you install ruby from ports or are you using the system ruby?
What does `ruby -v` or `which ruby`  show ?

Comment: Will `list installed` tell me the architecture it was built for as well? Or should that not matter? I installed ruby from ports and made sure all my Ruby / Rails / Sqlite3 binaries are found in `/opt/local` by `which`. I will take a look into RVM. Thanks :)

Comment: it won't tell you which arch you have installed, just the package name/versions.  I don't think your sqlite error is a arch error (well it could be linked to wrong arch, but if ).  Does gem list show the sqlite3 gem installed?   also see here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987572/sqlite-3-error-while-running-ror-application  looks like it could be issue with sqlite vs 1.3.x ..