# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_open_v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new at this ruby thing and i have this problem and i can´t find a solution.

after running the rails server $`rails s`

`dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_open_v2
  Referenced from: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace`

dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_open_v2
  Referenced from: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

I am using homebrew and rvm.

Version:
xcode: 3.1, sqlite3 3.7.8, ruby 1.9.2p290, Rails 3.1.1, Mac OS X 10.5.8

so please help me.

UPDATE:

if i put the image out of the index.html  `background-image: url("/assets/rails.png");` = it runs. but why??

Comment: It seems like your problem is similar to that one:


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard/1241484#1241484

Comment: thx @WarHog Yes and No! I don't have a mysql.bundle to remove and there is no sqlite3.bundle

Answer (score 1):

Check your ruby version and `bundle install` again to update after `rvm use 1.9.3` (or the version your application is in). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i'm just wondering if you try to delete sqlite3_native.bundle?

Comment: because he fixed it with delete.  "I finally deleted the mysql.bundle (I have no idea what this is for) and it all worked."@ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991708/rails-mysql-and-snow-leopard/1241484#1241484

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943110/153886 has an answer to a similar question. Shortly speaking you have a linking problem with your gem (when you run "bundle install" and it compiles your gem the gem gets linked to the sqlite3 library which does not exist). The link explains how to configure Bundler.

Comment: you could explain why this link might be useful.