# rails 3.1 'Symbol not found: _sqlite3_open_v2' sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

OK, I've been using sqlite3 as development successfully for this tiny rails 3.1 project, my first that's not an example, and want to move it over to a Leopard PPC machine. I've done so and have bundle installed my gems to PPC native versions as near as I can tell. I've built sqlite3 from source into /usr/local/ to ensure it's PPC native and is at version 3.7.9. I'm using rvm to use ruby 1.9.2 p290. My Gemfile references: gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.0'

When I bundle exec rake db:migrate I get the following error:

```
> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_open_v2  
> Referenced from:
> /Users/wanzie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
> Expected in: flat namespace
> 
> dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_open_v2   Referenced from:
> /Users/wanzie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
> Expected in: flat namespace
> 
> Trace/BPT trap
```

OK, looking around on stackoverflow, someone else had this problem on Leopard and suggested placing gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3' in the Gemfile.

This is the error I get:

```
> rake aborted! Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install
> activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add
> it to Gemfile.)
> 
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

There is a commonality with this particular Ruby, I see in other stackoverflow posts. And it appears that the sqlite3 app must match the version for the adapter. We know this is a bogus suggestion for this gem since it doesn't exist.

My question is, how do I fix this, since sqlite3 needs to be setup for PPC? thanx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is your solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943110/153886